# Pass form login credentials to module

Tags: sql, excel, vba, teradata, adodb

Is it possible to pass a variable from a Form to a module after the form is closed?

I created this login when opening Excel:
[image]

It uses the following code:

```vb
Option Explicit

Private Sub cmdLogin_Click()

    Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
    Dim Rc As ADODB.Recordset
    Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection
    Dim user As String
    Dim password As String
    Dim sConnect As String
    
    user = Me.txtUserID.Value
    password = Me.txtPassword.Value
    
    sConnect = "Driver={Teradata};DBCname=xxxxx;DatabaseName=xxxxx;Uid=" & user & ";Pwd=" & password & "; Authentication=LDAP;"
    
    Cn.Open sConnect
    
    If Cn.State = 1 Then
        Unload Me
        Application.Visible = True
    Else
        If LoginInstance < 3 Then
            MsgBox "Invalid login credentials. Please Try again.", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Invalid Login Details"
            LoginInstance = LoginInstance + 1
        Else
            MsgBox "You have exceeded the maximum number of login attempts.", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Invalid Credentials"
            Unload Me
            ThisWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False
            Application.Visible = True
            LoginInstance = 0
        End If
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub cmdSkip_Click()
    Unload Me
    Application.Visible = True
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
    Me.txtUserID.Value = ""
    Me.txtPassword.Value = ""
    Me.txtUserID.SetFocus
End Sub
```

With the login credentials I'm able to see if the user login connects to the server.

I have a module in which I want to run SQL query from that server:

```vb
    sConnect = "Driver={Teradata};DBCname=xxxxx;DatabaseName=xxxxx;Uid=" & user & ";Pwd=" & password & "; Authentication=LDAP;"
          
    Cn.Open sConnect
```

I want to store the username and password written during the login stage to use in the module.

Is this possible, because the form closes after logging in?

This is what the module should look like:

```vb
Public LoginInstance As Integer
Public user As String
Public password As String

Sub Extract_SUMMARY()

Dim Cn As ADODB.Connection
Dim Rc As ADODB.Recordset
Set Cn = New ADODB.Connection

table_query = "sql query"
summary_query = "sql query"

sConnect = "Driver={Teradata};DBCname=xxxx;DatabaseName=xxxxx;Uid=" & user & ";Pwd=" & password & "; Authentication=LDAP;"

Cn.Open sConnect

Set table_set = New ADODB.Recordset

table_set.Open table_query, Cn
Worksheets("Higher Level Analysis").Cells(2, 4).CopyFromRecordset table_set
table_set.Close

Set summary_set = New ADODB.Recordset

summary_set.Open summary_query, Cn
Worksheets("Higher Level Analysis").Cells(5, 1).CopyFromRecordset summary_set
summary_set.Close

Cn.Close

Set recset = Nothing

End Sub
```

I tried to create a public variable but I don't think it saves after the form is closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `Private` declarations for the respective variables, but use `Public` variables **in a standard module**:

```
Public userM As String 
Public passwordM As String
```

Then give them a value (in two ways):

```
Private Sub cmdSkip_Click()
    userM = user: passwordM = password
    Unload Me
    Application.Visible = True
End Sub
```

or use `Terminate` event:

```
Private Sub UserForm_Terminate()
   userM = user: passwordM = password
End Sub
```

You must understand that these variables are volatile, I mean, they are valid (staying in memory) until an error stopping the code appear... So, you can also save their value *in a hidden sheet*...

**Edited**:

In fact you can avoid all the above scenario, moving the existing variables **in a standard module**. They will be used from all project, form included... But still remains the volatility problem.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your feedback. Just few questions. Id declare the public variables in the module right? and the private sub would be then created in the module? Im just confused because I already declared Public user As String Public password As String as shown in the code, but they dont save for some reason. Could this be because the form closes and we loose that memory? Would the only option then be to Save it in a private sheet?

Comment: @King Like you said in your question, after closing the form, the variables (from form) value are lost. So, **You have to pass their value to variables able do be accessed from anywhere in the `VBProject`**. A standard module offers this opportunity. You can let your existing variables form the form code as `Public`, even if they cannot be used after closing the form. In such cases, usually they are declared `As Private`, but this is not mandatory. Like you see, I suggested creation of `Public` variables with different names (having a M at the end...). Just to differentiate (M from module)...

Comment: @King In fact, you can declare them **only in a standard module**, where from they can be used by the form, too... :)